# htaccess redirecting localhost to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

My Htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is working great and my website is https.

But I don't want it to do this for localhost because it's messing with my server-status and I need it to be http for localhost!

How can I do this?